Confusion on reading multiple ways of p implies q
So these are the different ways of expressing the conditional statement, and I got these from Rosen's Discrete Math Textbook:

So I want to be clear on a couple of things:

When we read all these statements, can we read them in long form by adding the phrase "is true" next to/after the q and p? Like could "if p, then q" be read as "if p is true, then q is true"?
If q if p is the same thing as saying if p then q or p -> q, then would p only if q be the same thing as saying if q is true, then p is true? From that perspective I have a hard time seeing how p -> q means the same thing as p only if q, especially when drawing out the truth table for it. I'm not sure if this is a language issue or something but it just feels weird how by adding the word "only" next to if in p only if q makes a different meaning from q if p.
Probably my most important question: I'm really having a hard time seeing why q unless (not P) is the same as p -> q, especially when I draw out the truth table for it where the columns don't match up:




p
q
p -> q
q unless (not p)




T
T
T
T


T
F
F
F


F
T
T
F


F
F
T
T



Since we know "unless" means "except on the condition that", p being false makes (not p) true, so q must be false then. Similarly p being true makes it that (not p) is false, so q should still be true then. Hence I filled the truth table accordingly.
I also saw someone else on MSE recommend that we instead use (not p) unless q instead, but when making the truth table I just get the same result
Kindly please help clarify my doubt here.


yes. 2. "if" means $\leftarrow$ and "only if" means $\to$. 3. "tea or coffee" means exclusive "or" in everyday speech but regular "or" in logic; "unless" means the same thing as "or", but you need the non-exclusive interpretation for this to make sense.



But why does "only if" mean →? 3. why are you talking about "or" here though, since my question was on "q unless (not p)"? Are they related?


If you pay I'll work. I'll work unless you don't pay.

Guys sorry I'm not following. Y'all see my truth table, right?

The third row in your truth table for "q unless (not p)" is wrong. As @NaïmFavier said, "unless" means "or", and therefore  "x or y" is true when one or both of x, y are true.

I tend to agree with OP that “X unless Y” is at least ambiguous in English.  The interpretation required here is “X is definitely true unless Y is true, in which case it could go either way.”  OP’s interpretation is “X is true unless Y is true, in which case X is false.”  The latter is often the intended meaning in English.  If I tell my child, “No dessert unless you eat your peas,” and then she eats her peas, and then I still say she can’t have dessert?… well, logic isn’t going to prevent a well-earned tantrum.

@BobMarley I suggest you break this post up into multiple posts asking fewer questions that are stated in a clear and focused manner.

The "is true" is usually considered to be part of the statements $p$ and $q$, so writing it again is redundant. For example, if $p$ is "$x$ is a prime greater than $2$" and $q$ is "$x$ is odd" then "$p$ only if $q$" translates to, "$x$ is a prime greater than $2$ only if $x$ is odd." You wouldn't say, "$x$ is a prime greater than $2$ is true only if $x$ is odd is true."

It seems to me that not all of the given translations are valid. For example, let $p$ be "$3$ is odd" and let $q$ be "$3$ is prime." Then it would technically be correct to say, "if $3$ is odd then $3$ is prime," but I would not say that "$3$ is prime" follows from "$3$ is odd."

@mjqxxxx You will earn a tantrum over dessert because the child already had a (presumably) reasonable expectation to receive dessert before you added the condition on eating their peas. It's this context that adds the "ambiguity" to the word "unless."

Keep in mind that, in classical logic, "p implies q" simply rules out the possibility that p is true AND q is false. $~~p \to q~~\equiv ~~\neg (p \land \neg q)~~$In "real-world" scenarios, we are talking about a snap-shot of the world, a single instant in time. Phrases like "q whenever p" suggest causality or a reference to some historical record. Also, "if p IS TRUE then q IS TRUE" leaves open the question, "what if  p IS FALSE?"

Your truth table for "Q unless not P" seems correct. It is logically equivalent to "P iff Q" (biconditional).

If you want everyday language, I'd say $p\to q$ means "whenever $p$ occurs $q$ occurs", which is equivalent to: "$q$ always occurs when $p$ does", "$p$ never occurs if $q$ doesn't", and "$p$ only occurs when $q$ does".  Although those 4 have different linguist significance (some are about $p$ and others are about $q$ and some are about when $p$ or $q$ does or doesn't occur) they are logically equivalent.  Each of your statements will seem to naturally correspond to one of the four. IMO the least intuitive is "$p$ only if $q$"="$p$ only occurs when $q$ does".

I'm not seeing why you think $p=F;q=T$ would mean "$q$ unless (not $p$)" is false.  I see "$A$ unless $B$" as meaning "the only way $A$ might be false is if $B$ is true.  If $A$ is true that statement is true as we don't have to worry if $A$ is false. If if $q$ is true "$q$ unless ANYTHING" is always true.  Likewise if $B$ is true, then "ANYTHING unless $B$" must be true as $B$ is the only way we can make $A$ false but $B$ is true so anything can happen.  So if $p$ is false and $q$ is true "q unless not p" is "TRUE unless TRUE" which to my mind is very true.

"we know "unless" means "except on the condition that"  But a single row on a truth table has no way to consider any exceptions, as exceptions belong to other rows.  This boils down to the common confusion that truth values can't evaluate causality.  We have no way of evaluating if $p$ caused $q$ or that  "if $p$ had happened then...".  We can only consider that statments are or are not true.  We can't in anyway make statements if any caused the other to be true.

Like the English 'or' (which can be inclusive or exclusive), the English 'unless' is ambiguous.
Consider:
Suppose a professor says: "You won't pass the course unless you complete all the HW's"
Well, this clearly means that if you don't complete all the HW's, you won't pass the course. But what if you do pass all the HW's ... will you now be guaranteed to pass the course?  I think it is clear that there is no such guarantee: you still need to do well on those HW's, as well as any quizzes, projects, midterm, final, etc. That is, it is perfectly possible (and compatible with the professor's claim) that you complete all the HW's, but still don't pass the course. Put differently:  completing all the HW's is a necessary condition for passing the course, but may well be not sufficient. Also: if you work out the truth-table for this, you'll see that you get 3 $T$'s, and 1 $F$, just like the material conditional: the only time the professor made a false claim is if you don't complete the HW's but still pass the course.
OK, but now compare this with:
"You can't take Calculus II unless you have taken Calculus I"
Well, under any normal circumstances, this can safely be taken to mean that taking Calculus I is not just necessary, but also sufficient for being able to take Calculus II. That is, now there are 2 ways for this statement to be false:  when you haven't taken Calculus I, but can still take Calculus II ... but also when you have taken Calculus I, but still can't take Calculus II.
So, it is as mjqxxx says in the Comments:
You took 'p unless q' to mean: "p is true as long as q is false ... but once q becomes true, p will cease to be the case" .. this is similar to the Calculus I and II example: "You cannot take Calculus II as long as you haven't taken Calculus I ... but once you have taken Calculus I you can take Calculus II"
But the text interprets 'p unless q' as: "p is true as long as q is false ... but once q becomes true, well, all bets are off as far as p goes". And that is more in line with the HW's example:  "You will not pass the course as long as you haven;t completed all HW's ... but once you do complete the HW's ... well, then you may or may not pass the course".

In other words, "unless" means "or" and both are ambiguous in the exact same way.

@NaïmFavier That's what it ends up being yes. Though I would not find that immediately obvious.

You might justify your truth table for $Q$ unless $\neg P$ with the following pseudo-code:
If $P$ then $Q$ = True
Else $Q$ = False.
So, when, as in your truth table,  $Q$ unless $\neg P$ is true (lines 1 and 4), $P$ and $Q$ will have the same truth values.
$~~Q~ unless ~\neg P ~~\equiv ~~ P \iff Q$

In addition...
Re: "$q$ whenever $p$"
This suggests to me a some kind of historical record:
$\forall t\in I: [p(t) \implies q(t)]$
Or equivalently...
$\forall t\in I: \neg [p(t) \land \neg q(t)]$
For some index set $I$, e.g. one or more point(s) in time.
Note that: "$p(t) \implies q(t)$" would be of indeterminate truth value for $t\notin I$.
